# Telnet connect to non-existing adress

Tags: networking, telnet, connectivity

I'm having unexpected behavior using the `telnet` command on various linux (Linux Mint, Ubuntu server).

When trying to connect to a non-existent device, it succeed. I tested with **`1.2.3.4` which is not a placeholder**.

#### Telnet

```
$ telnet 1.2.3.4 9100
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to 1.2.3.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

#### Ping

**fails as expected**, this is not the problem!

```
$ ping 1.2.3.4 -c 5
PING 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 1.2.3.4 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4076ms
```

#### Traceroute (update)

```
$ sudo traceroute -T -p telnet 1.2.3.4
traceroute to 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)  2.693 ms  3.166 ms  3.178 ms
```

#### Route

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.240   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br-427309471a28
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-427309471a28
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

Even when stopping `docker` I still can reproduce:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.240   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

#### Question

Here is [a recording](https://asciinema.org/a/e16ndw5jm81yyzfswrieofu83).

Why is `telnet` connecting on a device that doesn't exist?

Comment: Please traceroute to the address to try and see if there is a nearby middlebox i.e. a firewall doing something horribly confusing. Something like `traceroute -T -p telnet 1.2.3.4`, i.e. using the same TCP port as telnet does. (You can also try the mtr version of traceroute, it may return results faster).

Comment: Seems like icmp packets are being dropped. By a firewall rule

Comment: @sourcejedi updated to add `traceroute` output + recording: https://asciinema.org/a/e16ndw5jm81yyzfswrieofu83

Comment: This indicates the behaviour is coming from your local network.  Please post `route -n` as requested, to confirm that your computers are using the default route to reach 1.2.3.4.  If so, hop 1 should represent an IP address which is handled directly on the router.  Are the machines you tested on all connected to the same router?  What model is the router?

Comment: added `route -n` output, stopped `docker` service and still reproduce

Comment: Sounds very much like a transparent proxy on your network.

Comment: Another view on the same issue (by a collaborater) [Why the forwarded SSH port still seem open even with the endpoint failing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42860110/802365). @StéphaneChazelas how do I check/remove this transparent proxy?